# Fedora - Maven FATAL JRE Error

Tags: maven, java, fedora-25

I'm trying to run `mvn package` on Fedora 25 but I keep getting this error:

```
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/2.12.4/surefire-junit4-2.12.4.pom
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb46a290711, pid=20263, tid=0x00007fb46af4e700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b16) (build 1.8.0_111-b16)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b16 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x14f711]  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms+0x211
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /run/media/pichardo/Data/hacking/projects/personal/MetalesBC-Billing-System/hs_err_pid20263.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
/usr/bin/mvn: line 20: 20263 Aborted                 (core dumped) $M2_HOME/bin/mvn "$@"
```

> echo $JAVA_HOME is /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_121/

Does someone know why may this be happening?

Comment: Enable core dumps and then file a bug report?

Comment: Did you read the entire error message?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes I did, but got distracted, thanks

Comment: I would recomment to test with Oracle JDK..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the distribution's bug tracker for reporting bugs. StackOverflow is the wrong place for this. Packagers will watch the distribution's bug tracker, not other places on the internet.

Anyway, this is probably https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1415137 and a fix for this is being pushed right now. See https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2017-4076cf8494

Also, your JAVA_HOME seems to be ignored by maven. It's not used, as you can see OpenJDK is being used by maven in the crash report.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that too

Comment: Thnks, I changed the java provider to Oracle JDK and the problems was solved

Comment: Uh.. or you can update OpenJDK right now and use the fixed version.